# Duplicar linha visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Existe alguma tecla de atalho que replique a ação (ctrl c + ctrl v)?
Alem de ter que copiar apertar enter ou clicar na linha de baixo e colar, eu consigo duplicar essa linha com algum atalho?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Note que o ReSharper desfaz essa configuração. Se isso acontecer:

- Resharper
- Options
- Keyboard & Menus
- Selecione a opção de atalhos clássicos do Visual Studio.

Comment: cara, aqui nao funcionou e nao tem resharp, e um vs bem restrito que estou usando  =(

`Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web`   `Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL`
   `Microsoft .NET Framework`
   `Version 4.6.01055`

    `Installed Version: WD Express`
    
   `Visual Basic 2015   00325-40000-00000-AA674`
    `Microsoft Visual Basic 2015`
    
   `Visual C# 2015   00325-40000-00000-AA674`
    `Microsoft Visual C# 2015`
    
    `ASP.NET and Web Tools   14.0.20626.0`
`ASP.NET and Web Tools`

Answer (score 18):

Duas opções:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd>

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mas me parece que esses atalhos são do VS Code. O VS Studio andou adotando os mesmos?

Comment: A pergunta **NÃO É** sobre **Visual Code** ou **LINUX**. É sobre Visual Studio e Windows

Answer (score 6):

Há uma extenção para isso:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctlajoie.DuplicateSelection

Após instalar, Acesse: Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard.
procure pela comando que contenha 'duplicate'
informe o atalho que deseja (recomendável Ctrl+D) e clique em Assign. 
Pronto!

[image: Img]

Comment: Não instalou na minha versão.

25/05/2017 20:30:09 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Comment: Veja se já não há essa opção "Edit.DuplicateSelection" no seu visual studio. O meu não tinha, então foi necessário instalar. A partir daí é só associar o comando

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio conseguiu resolver ?

Comment: cara não tem a opção, não consegui resolver infelizmente =/

Comment: Tente a solução por macro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279000/visual-studio-short-cut-key-duplicate-line

Answer (score 3):

Vá em File (Arquivo) >> Preferences >> Keyboard Shortcuts

No campo de pesquisa digite copy line down

Clique no lápis (editar) e um campo de texto aparecerá

Aperte a combinação de CTRL+D

Pronto! ;)

Answer (score 2):

A melhor opções, no meu caso (Linux Mint) foi:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Se você não seleciona nada, ele vai copiar a linha completa.

Dessa forma é mesma coisa de usar o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> de outros editores *(apesar de que no VS Code tem que usar dois atalhos de teclados para ter o mesmo resultado de editores como Sublime ou Notepad++, mas isso não é algo banal, dá pra sobreviver sem, na minha opinião)*.

Answer (score 1):

#### Amigo a função para copiar uma linha para CIMA ou par BAIXO é:

shift + alt + down

ou

shift + alt + up

**Listar todos os atalhos do vscode:**

**Windows/Linux:** Ctrl + k Ctrl + s

Comment: A pergunta **NÃO É** sobre **Visual Code** ou **LINUX**. É sobre Visual Studio e Windows

Answer (score 0):

No VS CODE
é igual o amigo falou

ctrl+alt+ seta pra baixo

Só no Visual Studiio 2010 não existe essa função, a melhor forma é ctrl+C e ctrl+V(Não precisa selecionar a linha inteira automaticamente ele já copia a linha inteira.)

Answer (score -4):

No vs code versão 1.28.x para duplicar vc usa ctrl+shift+alt seta pra baixo ou para cima.

Comment: A pergunta **NÃO É** sobre **Visual Code**. É sobre Visual Studio.